# Set ELB as Autoscaling Health Check Type in Elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created an environment using Elastic Beanstalk with load balancer & have assign all health check values in respective configuration

I have also set application health check url for ELB

But when I check autoscaling group config, health check type is EC2. How do I change health check type to ELB using elastic beanstalk

Answer (score 0):

You have to set it in a config that goes in your **.ebextensions** folder. This article is useful: https://github.com/ThoughtWorksStudios/eb_deployer/wiki/Elastic-Beanstalk-Tips-and-Tricks

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
$ cat .ebextensions/0090_healthcheckurl.config 
Resources:
   AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
     Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup"
     Properties:
       HealthCheckType: "ELB"
       HealthCheckGracePeriod: "600"
option_settings:
  - namespace:  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application
    option_name:  Application Healthcheck URL
    value:  /_status
```